# Standard icon for SMS

Tags: website-design, icon

I've been working on a website where there will be two buttons: "Call us" and an "SMS us". The user might be on mobile or on a desktop browser, and I'd like to make it clear that the SMS icon means "send an SMS" not "whatsapp us".

There will be text on the buttons but I'm looking for an icon that better represents "send us an sms" specifically, not chatting. Most of the icons I've found are either a variation of the chat bubble (square, round) or it says "SMS" inside the bubble, like these examples https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=sms&m=free

When I do a google search I get many other variations, some with the balloon inside / on top of a mobile icon, some with 2 balloons implying a chat, some with an envelope (which can be confused with "email") but I'm wondering: is there one  that is the "standard" for SMS icon?

Comment: Look on the [noun project](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=SMS). As far as I know there is no such thing as a standard icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not one standard SMS icon at this point in time.

I think variations of a chat bubble is the closest, with SMS inside or a phone icon behind the bubble if you need that much clarity.

Answer (score 0):

try using an envelop icon, this is the worldwide known message icon.

Comment: Or is that the email icon, as I mentioned in the question? How to differentiate?